# ANT concat extract only part of each file

Tags: regex, xml, ant

With a collection of xml files similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<title>xxxx</title>

<prolog>
    <metadata>
         <othermeta name="xxxx/>
        <othermeta name="xxxx/>
    </metadata>
</prolog>
<p>
  Blah blah blah blah
</p>
```

(simplified example)

I want to go through each file and extract just the `<prolog></prolog>` sections into one output file.

This is not working:

```
<project name="export_metadata" default="all" basedir=".">
 <target name="all" depends="extract"/>

 <target name="extract">
  <concat destFile="allMetadata.xml">
    <fileset dir=".">
       <include name="**/*.xml"/>
    </fileset>
    <filterchain>
      <tokenfilter>
          <replaceregex pattern="&lt;.*?(&lt;prolog&gt;.*?&lt;/prolog&gt;).*?/p&gt;" replace="\1" flags="gs" />
      </tokenfilter>
    </filterchain>
  </concat>

 </target>
</project>
```

It puts the entire contents of each file into allMetadata.xml, rather than the prolog sections.

I've used replaceregexp and capturing groups successfully for some time now, but I think I'm not getting something about how tokenfilters work here.

The regular expression and substitution works when I try it in regex101.com. It seems that `pattern` and `replace` here should match the entire page, capture the prolog section in a group, and replace the entire page with that group, then output that. But no luck. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I ended up doing this a different way (filtering to just affect the tags in the XML file that I wanted, see below) but I just saw the answer below and now I see why my original approach wasn't working, good to know.

I'm doing this now instead:

```
<target name="extract">
 <concat destFile="allMetadata_Guide.xml">
     <fileset dir=".">
       <include name="**/*.dita"/>
     </fileset>
    <filterchain>
     <linecontainsregexp>
        <regexp pattern="&lt;othermeta|&lt;title&gt;|content=&quot;"/>
    </linecontainsregexp>
   </filterchain>
 </concat>
</target>
```

I want to transform lines that contain `othermeta`, or `title`, or `content=`, so this now works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LineTokenizer is the default tokenizer of `<tokenfilter>`. LineTokenizer passes one line at a time to `<replaceregex>`. Your regex won't match patterns over multiple lines.

Use FileTokenizer instead to ensure that `<replaceregex>` is called only once for the entire input file:

```
<tokenfilter>
    <filetokenizer/>
    <replaceregex
        pattern="&lt;.*?(&lt;prolog&gt;.*?&lt;/prolog&gt;).*?/p&gt;"
        replace="\1" flags="gs" />
</tokenfilter>
```

Comment: It's not working for me. I'm getting this error: "concat doesn't support the nested "tokenfilter" element". Can you help?

Comment: The tokenfilter goes under filterchain, not concat.